# Can maximal compact subgroups of subgroups be extended to maximal compact subgroups of the ambient Lie group?

Tags: lie-groups

Given a Lie group $G$ and a closed subgroup $U \subset G$:

- Is it always possible to choose a maximal compact subgroup $K \subset G$ of $G$ such that $K \cap U$ is again a maximal compact subgroup of $U$?
- Or equivalently: Given a maximal compact subgroup $K' \subset U$ of $U$, is it possible to extend $K'$ to a maximal compact subgroup $K$ of $G$?

Suppose the answer to the above is affirmative or reasonable criteria can be given:

- How about several subgroups $U_1, U_2 \subset G$? Can we choose a maximal compact subgroup $K_{1,2} \subset U_1 \cap U_2$ and extensions to maximal compact subgroups $K_1 \subset U_1$ and $K_2 \subset U_2$ which then both allow for a single, common extension to a maximal compact subgroup $K \subset G$?

I have very little knowledge about Lie groups for now, so any help and any hints to helpful references are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

*Every* compact subgroup of a connected Lie group (or actually any Lie group with finitely many connected components) is contained in a maximal one.  I believe this should be proved in most basic texts on Lie groups. See, for instance, Theorem 14.1.3 on page 531 in *Structure and Geometry of Lie Groups*, by Hilgert and Neeb. In particular, the maximal compact subgroup of any closed subgroup is contained in a maximal one.

This answers the first two (equivalent) questions. Regarding the third: no, this is not always possible. At least I'm pretty sure. The idea is this: take two compact subgroups $U_1,U_2$ in (say) $G=\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $U_1 \cup U_2$ generates a non-compact subgroup. I believe this should be possible (for $n>1$). Then $K_1=U_1,K_2=U_2$ are the unique maximal compact subgroups of $U_1,U_2$ respsectively, but they do not admit a common extension.

Comment: Regarding your second paragraph, with $G=GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, I think the group generated by the union of *all* the compact subgroups of $G$ is the set of matrices with $\det=\pm 1$.  The point is that the image of $\det$ on a compact subgroup is a compact subgroup of $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$, so is a subgroup of $\{\pm 1\}$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Thank you, you are right. I changed it to SL. Although the important thing is that they don't generate a compact subgroup, of course.